# NavBar Transition CSS Trouble

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Navbar which makes a transition when I scroll down.
When I scroll up, the transition doesn't work and I don't know why. Can someone help me resolve this?

The JS code is adding the scrolled class when `Math.round($(window).scrollTop()) > 100`.

```css
@supports (position: sticky) {
    body {
      padding-top: 0;
    }

    header {
      position: sticky;
    }

}

.scrolled {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
   }

.scrolled.header {
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
  }

.scrolled.header .header-menu {
    line-height: 40px; 
    transition: 0.5s ease;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="header-logo"><i class="fas fa-signal"></i>NAME</a>
        <nav class="header-menu">
            <a href="#">Accueil</a>
            <a href="#">Compétences</a>
            <a href="#">Parcours</a>
            <a href="#">Projets</a>
            <a href="#">Hobbies</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <a href="#" class="toggle" id="burgerButton">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! In order for folks to help they generally appreciate an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the behavior describe and fully troubleshoot the issue. As it sits if we can't reproduce the issue then it may be left to assumptions/guessing. As it sits we're note sure what the `transition-property` is in the first place and it'd difficult to visualize the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly : When you scroll down you add the .scrolled class, and when you move up you remove it ?
If so, you should also add the transition : 0.5s ease; to the nav-bar itself. Because when you remove the .scrolled class, why would a transition occure if the nav haven't this specified in it's css ?

Comment: Thanks , it's fixed now ! the transition was on my navbar but as "0,5s ease" that's why it didn't work ... my bad.

Comment: I'm happy it helped you !